# Problema con Interfaz gráfica, visualización de menu en TK Python

Tags: python, tkinter

no puedo lograr que aparezca el menu en la interfaz gráfica de python. ¿Alguien sabe cómo hacer? últimas versiones de tk y python instadas.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5
```

cuando lo instalé me pidió instalar tk por separado

tkinter is no longer included with this formula, but it is available separately:
brew install python-tk@3.11

lo cual hice.

Me funcionan botones, Entries y todo lo demás q he probado. Pero no menues, el código es:

```
import tkinter as tk

def dummy_command():
    print("Submenú seleccionado")


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Interfaz con Menús")

# Crear la barra de menú
barra_menu = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=barra_menu)

# Crear los menús principales
menu_archivo = tk.Menu(barra_menu)
menu_edicion = tk.Menu(barra_menu)
menu_herramientas = tk.Menu(barra_menu)

# Agregar los menús principales a la barra de menú
barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=menu_archivo)
barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Edición", menu=menu_edicion)
barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Herramientas", menu=menu_herramientas)

# Crear submenús para cada menú principal
for i in range(4):
    menu_archivo.add_command(label=f"Archivo {i+1}", command=dummy_command)
    menu_edicion.add_command(label=f"Edición {i+1}", command=dummy_command)
    menu_herramientas.add_command(label=f"Herramienta {i+1}", command=dummy_command)

root.mainloop()
```

Aclaración: soy amateur y tengo una MacBook 2017

desde ya gracias!

Comment: Pareciera que el código está bien escrito. Copié tu código (gracias por hacer un emcv :)) y me funciona perfecto. El problema es que yo lo probé en Windows 10 y Python 3.10. Tal vez sea un problema de versiones superiores y/o del sistema operativo.

Comment: Encontré [una pagina oficial](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/), tal vez este fragmento tenga relación con el error: `Si está utilizando macOS 10.6 o posterior , el Tcl/Tk 8.5 suministrado por Apple tiene errores graves que pueden provocar fallos de la aplicación. Si desea utilizar IDLE o Tkinter, no utilice los Python proporcionados por Apple. En su lugar, instale y utilice una versión más reciente de Python de python.org o un distribuidor externo que proporcione o enlace con una versión más reciente de Tcl/Tk.` (traducción automatica)

Comment: gracias Dante por tu ayuda :)

descubrí que Mac lleva los menués a la parte superior  de cualquier aplicación y efectivamente allí estaban. 

abrazo!